# "Invalid expression" error while rendering vue.js component's id

Tags: vue.js

I created a component:

```
Vue.component("foo", {
    template: '<div class="foo" :id={{id}}></div>',
    data: function() {
        return {
            id: "bar" 
        }
    }
})
```

This errors out on `:id={{id}}` with `Error compiling template: invalid expression: expected property name, got '{'`.

Assuming the `bar`'s ID is unique, why does this error out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write : 
`template: '<div class="foo" :id="id"></div>'`

Curly brackets should be used between `html` tags

e.g : `template: '<div class="foo" :id="id">{{id}}</div>'`

Comment: Thanks, this was it.  Where is this explained in the documentation?

Comment: @alex you can check here : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text and here : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

Answer (score 0):

When you are using v-bind or ":" for binding an attribute you should not have double brackets "{{}}"

```
 template: '<div class="foo" :id="id"></div>'
```